# ajax js serialize not reading form elements

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, prototypejs

Have a form that is not being read by serialize() function.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function submitTrans1(){
  var formData = $('form1').serialize();
  var options = {
   method:'post',
   postBody:'formData',
   onCreate: function(){alert(formData)},
      onSuccess: function(transport){alert("onSuccess alert \n" + transport.responseText);},
   onComplete: function(){alert('complete');},
   onFailure: function(){alert('Something went wrong...')}
   }

  new Ajax.Request('/clients/addTrans/<?=$clientID123?>/',options);
 }
 </script>
  <?php
  $datestring = "%Y-%m-%d";
  $time = time();
  $clid1 = $this->uri->segment(3);
  ?>
  <form name="form1" id="form1">
   <div id="addTransDiv" style="display:none">

     <div class="">
      <label for="transDesc" id="transDesc" value="sadf" class="preField">Description</label>
      <textarea cols="40" rows="3" id="transDesc" value="" name="transDesc" class=""></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="">
      <label for="date" class="preField">Date</label>
      <input type="date" id="transDate" name="date" value="<?=mdate($datestring, $time);?>" size="40" class=""/><br/>
     </div>
     <div class="">
      <label for="userfile" class="preField">File</label>
      <input type="file" name="transFile" id="userfile" size="20" /><br>
     </div>
     <input type="button" id="submitTrans" name="submitTrans" value="Submit" onclick="submitTrans1()">

   </div>
  </form>
```

Uh, I have an alert in the onSuccess parameter of the Ajax.Request that would ideally alert the variable assigned to the serialized form. However, when it alerts, it alerts nothing. I also have the processing url printing out the $_POST data just in case, but that as well returns an empty array in the responseText, so indeedidly nothing is being posted to the form.

### Thx.

Edit1

it seems that the problem might be related to the fact that the form is inside a div. If I remove everything on the page except for the form and js, it works ok. But the form is in a div that is hidden by default and uses another function to be displayed. Is there some kind of magic needed to get form data via serialize if it's in a div?

---

Edit 2

Tried adding quotes and pound signs and all that other jazz. I am using web developer toolbar, firebug, etc... it isn't throwing any js errors and doesn't afraid of anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erroneous table does the breaking.

I had the form within a table with no tr's or td's (not sure if the last part matters) and upon removing the table tags, everything is working.

The relevant js now looks like:

```
var formData = $('form1').serialize();
var options = {
   method:'post',
   postBody:formData,
 [...]
```

I'd like to thank the Academy, and all those that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes from around the variable name formData in the postBody field.

The web developer toolbar in Firefox is as useful as anything for debugging client-side javascript.

BTW, the snippet contains a few undefined items, like the JS function showTransAdd(), several PHP variables, the PHP function mdate(), and the inclusion of the prototype library.

Comment: Thanks. However, if the variable is echoing blank in the alert, doesn't that ultimately mean nothing is getting passed to the formData var? I mean if nothing is in the alert(formData) nothing will be in the postBody with or without quotes, no?

Also, the other function and vars are defined, just outside of the scope of the code I'm fighting. 

Thanks again.

Comment: As with Adam, my toy copy worked too.  And it did have the div, but I had to remove style='display:none' to see the button.   Perhaps the implementation of the showTransAdd() function is important here.   One thought, does it help to put the 'display:none' directive in the CSS for #addTransDiv?  That, or put the display:none on the form instead of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
var formData = $('form1').serialize();
```

to this:

```
var formData = $('#form1').serialize();
```

I had to change several other things to make a working copy, but I'm not sure about what all code you withheld or how your environment may differ.  If that doesn't work, I can send you the full code snippet I used.

Comment: Thanks. However, adding the pound sign causes triggers a js error [('#form1') is null)]. 

The page has over 1,000 lines of code, so I guessed it better not to paste the whole thing ;) Undoubtedly the problem lies on line 521, but it's not enough of a problem to trigger any errors in the normal sense... Here's to consolidation!